# jQuery carousel plugin with flexibility

Tags: jquery, plugins, carousel

I am looking for a plugin that allows you to show three images at once but lets you hide half of the 1st and the 3rd image (making the center image the focal at given point).  I have seen jCarouselLite (http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/) and jCarousel(http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/). Both let you show 3 images at once but doesn't let you do what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the CSS for the plugin to see if you could modify it? Usually the carousel has a CSS "window" that can be manipulated for width.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I don't quite understand what you're tyring to achieve, but http://slidesjs.com/ and http://nivo.dev7studios.com/ are both really good options and flexible.